# WebStorm + RubyMine together(?)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea, webstorm, rubymine

I'm a longstanding Rubymine user. Rubymine was great for html-based Rails apps, but I'm now doing lots more SPA client work (e.g. javascript / react). I'm finding that I really would like to use WebStorm for all of the client stuff (esp module autocompletion, es6 support, etc.).

Having said that, I'm still using Rails' asset pipeline to deliver the client code, so these projects aren't trivial to separate...

Can someone suggest how to get the best of WebStorm (for the client side) and RubyMine (for the server side) working well together in dev environment? There is some promise in the approach mentioned [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-343) but maybe there's a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need 2 separate products at all? What WebStorm has that RubyMine does not (except, possibly, some lighter/simpler project configuration). All functionality of the WebStorm should be included in RubyMine/PyCharm/PhpStorm as well -- 1) as long as you compare the same branches 2) you may need to install some plugins manually. For example: PhpStorm is basically WebStorm + PHP + DB/SQL support

Comment: Hmmm... I'm just not seeing that. A million examples: code completion templates for js (and es6 and jsx), React support, Yeoman integration, JSLint support, support for grunt, etc. Even trivial things like File>New... doesn't list much beyond the basics (for client side). In fairness, I'm comparing RubyMine 8.5 (EAP) against WebStorm 11, so maybe it is just way behind? Sorry to be so dumb about this - I would be super delighted if you help me get near feature parity and stay with  one IDE! That would be awesome!

Answer (score 3):

All the features for client-side development supported by WebStorm are either included out-of-the-box in RubyMine or available as plugins in the plugin repository. You do not need to use two different IDEs.

Comment: Thanks, yole. please see my comment to LazyOne above. I did look at all the plugins and *did* see Yeoman, but nothing for grunt, jslint, react, jsx, ... (in fairness, JSX does seem to be supported).

Comment: @Eric *"but nothing for grunt, jslint, react, jsx, ... (in fairness, JSX does seem to be supported)."* they all part of JavaScript support and not separate plugins. For JSX you need to "switch language version to JSX Harmony manually" in Settings/Preferences (at least it's how it works in PhpStorm for sure)